# how to clean boost::asio::ssl::stream after closed by server

Tags: sockets, networking, ssl, boost, boost-asio

Currently I am developing a gateway to connect apns to push notification. Apns will close the ssl socket when the connection is idle for about one hour. Sometimes when I reconnect, boost.asio keep telling me that handshake fail with error code 335544539. When apns close the connection, I will call socket.close(), but I didn't shutdown ssl stream. How could I clean ssl stream so that I could reconnect by using the old ssl stream?

Comment: Please take a [tour].

Comment: If its an underlying OpenSSL error, then 335544539 is 0x140000DB. And `openssl errstr 0x140000DB` returns `error:140000DB:SSL routines:SSL routines:short read`.