# What does this error error:140000DB:SSL routines:SSL routines:short read means

Tags: ssl, asio

In our software, we are keep getting this warning/error message intermittently. Not sure how/why this message appears.

> HTTP asio handshake failed: error:140000DB:SSL routines:SSL
>   routines:short read

I searched in the Internet, but the mostly the result pointing me to a VMware problem. Which not the case for me.

Until I found out that actually this error is thrown by OpenSSL that is used by Boost-Asio. I have downloaded the source code of OpenSSL/Asio/Boost but couldn't find this error code in the source. My question, Is there anyone knows what this error means? What could be the trigger of this error message? I just want to understand a bit to find out the reproduction. So we can fix our software if there is any hole in the software.

Many Thanks in advance!

Reference:
http://ib-krajewski.blogspot.my/2016/03/https-support-for-casablanca-client.html

[how to clean boost::asio::ssl::stream after closed by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263381/how-to-clean-boostasiosslstream-after-closed-by-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A commit in OpenSSL removed the error `SSL_R_SHORT_READ`.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/45f55f6a5bdcec411ef08a6f8aae41d5d3d234ad)

[The commit before before OpenSSL removed the error `SSL_R_SHORT_READ` still has it defined as 219 == 0xDB.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/616f71e486d693991b594439c884ec624b32c2d4/ssl/ssl.h#L3014) This error of 0xDB is what comes out of OpenSSL as 0x140000DB.

In general a short read happens on TCP when the connection ended before the other side could send enough data to decode the current message. This may happen for example because the other side crashed or a network problem.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for this. How about the error for 0x140000DB? In the second link I put above, someone mentioned that this error is also coming from OpenSSL which I couldn't find. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, it is helpful. I was confused because I thought 335544539 == 0x140000DB. How can you say 0xDB is the same to 0x140000DB? Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause for my problem. There is mismatch of cipher the host and the client that trying to connect to. Then this error is thrown from the client.

Comment: That server is not correctly implemented, it should send a handshake failure alert before closing the connection, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3 .